# Storing a look up table in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I need to store a look up table in TCL. Here is a short section of it:

[image]

When searching in the table, I shall get an input for the last column called ADC here. Usually, the input will not match a value in the last column so I will use the closest two numbers to carry out a linear interpolation so I can get the output for the first three columns.

e.g if the input is 4000, the closest numbers are in 3rd and 4th row which are 4016 and 3986. I will then use linear interpolation to find what temperature value exists between -55 and -50 when the ADC is 4000. The same will be done for the voltage (3.3V) and voltage (1V) to carry out a linear interpolation.

Whata structure should I use to store this type of table in TCL?

Answer (score 2):

You'll use a dict.

You can populate it like this (assuming your data is in a space-separated file)

```
set lookup {}
set fh [open input.file]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    lassign $line temp v3 v1 adc
    foreach item {temp v3 v1} {dict set lookup $acd $item [set $item]}
}
close $fh
```

`lookup` now contains data like this

```
puts $lookup
# => 4034.9711 {temp -80 v3 3.2508 v1 0.9851} 4016.0490 {temp -55 v3 3.2355 v1 0.9804} ...
```

Then if you have an input ADC like 4020, the interpolated temp can be:

```
set input 4020

set up [lindex [dict keys $lookup] 0]
dict for {low _} $lookup {
    if {$low <= $input && $input < $up} then break else {set up $low}
}
# up  = 4034.9711
# low = 4016.0490

set t_up  [dict get $lookup $up temp]     ;# => -80
set t_low [dict get $lookup $low temp]    ;# => -55
set t [expr {$t_low + ($t_up - $t_low) * ($up - $input) / ($up - $low)}]
puts $t
# => -74.7799134345554
```

---

With @Chris's hint:

```
set adcs [lsort -real [dict keys $lookup]]
set idx [lsearch -bisect $adcs $input]
set low [lindex $adcs $idx]     ;# => 4016.0490
set up  [lindex $adcs 1+$idx]   ;# => 4034.9711
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I am just a bit confused by the "Item" in the first code block. So item will be one of temp, v3 and v1 at a time. And then we do {dict set lookup $acd $item [set $item]}. The *$item [set $item]}* is not clear. What is happening here that require mentioning item multiple times?

Comment: If using at least Tcl8.6, you can also use `lsearch -bisect` to help with inexact searching.

Comment: the variable `item` contains the _string_ value "temp". To access the value of the _variable_ "temp", we need to use `set $item` (where in other languages we might be able to "double dereference" `$$item`)

Comment: I'm wondering whether doing this task in SQLite would be more sensible. I've not looked in detail at it though.